# Value in countUp and even in typography not updating

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to modify the proyect of { https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=khJlrj3Y6Ls&t=3311s } to my country, so, instead of having countries displayed in the option box and selecting one for updating the value of the cards, I'm trying to achieve to update the numbers when selecting a region, one by one... **The options and region names are done.**
But, when selecting a region the number is not updating and just displays zero, even is receiving the correct data in JSON (and even passing a number it just desplays zero).
I'm sorry if I'm a bit ambiguous but I'm newbie in React. How I can achieve this?, it just displays zero... And I have a lot of hours trying to resolve this.
Thanks and also, the 99% of the work is from the tutorial of JavaScript Mastery.
**There's the code.**

```
    import axios from 'axios';

const url = 'https://covid19.mathdro.id/api/countries/CHILE';
export const fetchData = async (provincia) => {
    let changeableUrl = url;
    if (provincia) {
        changeableUrl = `${url}/confirmed`;
        try {
            const {
                data: [  
                    confirmed,
                    recovered,
                    deaths,
                    lastUpdate,
            ]
            } = await axios.get(changeableUrl);
            return {
                confirmed,
                recovered,
                deaths,
                lastUpdate,
            };
        } catch (error) {
            return error;
        }
    } else {
        try {
            const {
                data: {
                    confirmed,
                    recovered,
                    deaths,
                    lastUpdate,
                }
            } = await axios.get(changeableUrl);

            return {
                confirmed,
                recovered,
                deaths,
                lastUpdate,
            };
        } catch (error) {
            return error;
        }
    }
};

export const fetchDailyData = async () => {
    try {
        const {
            data
        } = await axios.get(`${url}`);

        return data.map(({
            confirmed,
            deaths,
            reportDate: date
        }) => ({
            confirmed: confirmed.total,
            deaths: deaths.total,
            date
        }));
    } catch (error) {
        return error;
    }
};

export const fetchCountries = async () => {
    try {
        const {data: provincias } = await axios.get(`${url}/confirmed`);
        return provincias.map((provincia) => provincia.provinceState);
    } catch (error) {
        return error;
    }
};
```

There's the APP.js

```
    import React from 'react';

// import Cards from './components/Cards/Cards.jsx';
// import Chart from './components/Chart/Chart.jsx';
// import CountryPicker from './components/CountryPicker/CountryPicker.jsx';

import {Cards, Chart, CountryPicker} from './components';
import styles from './App.module.css';
import { fetchData} from './api';
// Acá se agrega el componente
class App extends React.Component {
    state = {
        data: {},
        provincia: '',
    }

    async componentDidMount(){
        const fetchedData = await fetchData();

        this.setState({ data: fetchedData })
    }

    handleCountryChange = async (provincia) => {
        const fetchedData = await fetchData(provincia);
        console.log(fetchedData)
        this.setState({ data: fetchedData, provincia: provincia })
    }


    render() {
        const { data, provincia} = this.state;


        return (
            <div className={styles.container}>
                <Cards data={data} />
                <CountryPicker handleCountryChange = {
                    this.handleCountryChange
                }
                />
                <Chart data={data} provincia={provincia} />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default App;
```

CARDS.js

```
    import React from 'react';
import { Card, CardContent, Typography, Grid } from '@material-ui/core';
import CountUp from 'react-countup';
import cx from 'classnames';

import styles from './Cards.module.css';

const Cards = ({ data :{confirmed, recovered, deaths, lastUpdate}}) => {

    if(!confirmed) {
        return 'Cargando...';
    }

    return(
        <div className={styles.container}>
        <Grid container spacing={3} justify="center">
            <Grid item component={Card} xs={12} md={3} className={cx(styles.card, styles.infectados)}>
                <CardContent>
                    <Typography color="textSecondary"       gutterBottom>Casos Totales</Typography>
                    <Typography variant="h5">
                        <CountUp  start={0} end={confirmed.value} duration={2.5} separator=","
                        />
                    </Typography>
                    <Typography         color="TextSecondary">{new Date(lastUpdate).toLocaleDateString()}</Typography>
                    <Typography variant="body2">Número de Casos Totales de COVID-19</Typography>
                </CardContent>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item component={Card} xs={12} md={3} className={cx(styles.card, styles.recuperados)}>
                <CardContent>
                    <Typography color="textSecondary" gutterBottom>Recuperados</Typography>
                    <Typography variant="h5">
                        <CountUp  start={0} end={recovered.value} duration={2.5} separator=","
                        />
                    </Typography>
                    <Typography         color="TextSecondary">{new Date(lastUpdate).toLocaleDateString()}</Typography>
                    <Typography variant="body2">Número de Casos Recuperados Totales de COVID-19</Typography>
                </CardContent>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item component={Card} xs={12} md={3} className={cx(styles.card, styles.muertes)}>
                <CardContent>
                    <Typography color="textSecondary"       gutterBottom>Muertes</Typography>
                    <Typography variant="h5">
                        <CountUp  start={0} end={deaths.value} duration={2.5} separator=","
                        />
                    </Typography>
                    <Typography         color="TextSecondary">{new Date(lastUpdate).toLocaleDateString()}</Typography>
                    <Typography variant="body2">Número de muertes totales causadas por COVID-19</Typography>
                </CardContent>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Cards;
```

And the COUNTRYPICKER.js (regionpicker in my case)

```
    import React, { useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import { NativeSelect, FormControl } from '@material-ui/core';

import styles from './CountryPicker.module.css';

import { fetchCountries } from '../../api';

const CountryPicker = ({
        handleCountryChange
    }) => {

    const [fetchedCountries, setFetchedCountries] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchAPI = async () => {
            setFetchedCountries(await fetchCountries());
        }

        fetchAPI();

    }, [setFetchedCountries]);


    return ( 
        <FormControl className={styles.formControl}>
            <NativeSelect defaultValue = ""
            onChange = {
                (e) => {
                     handleCountryChange(e.target.value)
                     
                }
            } >
{/* Lo siguiente es para el selector de países */}
                <option value="Chile">Todo Chile</option>
                {fetchedCountries.map((provincia, i) => <option key={i} value={provincia}>{provincia}</option>)}
            </NativeSelect>

        </FormControl>
    )
}

export default CountryPicker;
```

[At first it is updating correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLLUo.png)

[JSON when it is updating at correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8K8SQ.png)

[Then, when selecting a region it is not updating and just displays zero](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGq3x.png)

[JSON when it is not displaying correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRUnN.png)

Comment: Please post the code for your component. You've just posted the axios requests.

Comment: @JMadelaine there is... thank you :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is the API response format for the provincia data.

I fixed it doing this in the api/index.js

```
export const fetchData = async (provincia) => {
    let changeableUrl = url;
    if (provincia) {
        changeableUrl = `${url}/confirmed`;
        try {
            const data = await axios.get(changeableUrl);
            const filteredData = data.data.find((province) => {
                 if (province.provinceState == provincia){
                    return province;
                };
            })
            return {confirmed: {value: filteredData.confirmed} , recovered: {value: filteredData.recovered} , deaths: {value: filteredData.deaths}, 
                        lastUpdate: new Date(filteredData.lastUpdate).toISOString()};
        } catch (error) {
            return error;
        }
    } else {
        try {
            const {
                data: {
                    confirmed,
                    recovered,
                    deaths,
                    lastUpdate,
                }
            } = await axios.get(changeableUrl);

            console.log("fetchdata else: ", confirmed,
                    recovered,
                    deaths,
                    lastUpdate);
            return {
                confirmed,
                recovered,
                deaths,
                lastUpdate,
            };
        } catch (error) {
            return error;
        }
    }
};
```

Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: I gave your reponse to be "useful", but since I do not have 15 of reputation it didn't show public... I seriously don't know how to thank you... THANKS! :)